# “Responsible for” vs. “responsible to”

Tags: word-usage

1.Method responsible to retrieve active offices by country.

2.Method responsible for retrieve active offices by country.

For and To when to use? That's right ?

Comment: This question is more appropriate at the related site [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm responsible for taking out the garbage.  I'm responsible to my wife.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. "Responsible" is a word used of people (or quasi-people like jobs or departments): it is not a property of methods.

So you can have

> Person/office responsible for retriev**ing** active offices by country.

but I don't even quite understand what you intend by "method responsible".